# How to add category and product using JSTL,JAVAEE,EJB , EL and Servlet for following?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, ejb, jstl, el

I am trying to make it possible to add Category and add Product (items) through my admin interface but I am unable to make it insert into database. I am learning javaee and following ecommerce tutorial here https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/intro.html  but this application lacks many things so I am trying to add features specially in admin part. But the CRUD is not working at all.

I have presented codes for everything that may be dependent for the i have explained above. The primary problem area are AdminServlet, addCategory.jsp, categoryManager and ProductManager.

I am using MySQL
Netbeans IDE
JAVA EE 8
EL
EJB
JSTL
MVC

**Admin Servlet:**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package controller;


import entity.Category;
import entity.Customer;
import entity.CustomerOrder;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.HttpConstraint;
import javax.servlet.annotation.ServletSecurity;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import session.CategoryFacade;
import session.CategoryManager;
import session.CustomerFacade;
import session.CustomerOrderFacade;
import session.OrderManager;
import validate.Validator;

/**
 *
 * @author Admin
 */
@WebServlet(name = "AdminServlet", 
            loadOnStartup = 1,
            urlPatterns = {
                            "/admin/",
                            "/admin/viewOrders",
                            "/admin/viewCustomers",
                            "/admin/customerOrder",
                            "/admin/orderRecord",
                            "/admin/logout",
                            "/admin/showCategory",
                            "/admin/addCategory",
                            "/admin/addProduct"

                            })
@ServletSecurity( @HttpConstraint(rolesAllowed = {"eshopAdmin"}) )
public class AdminServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @EJB
    private OrderManager orderManager;
    @EJB
    private CategoryManager categoryManager;
    @EJB
    private CustomerFacade customerFacade;

    @EJB
    private CategoryFacade categoryFacade;
    @EJB
    private CustomerOrderFacade customerOrderFacade;


    private Customer customer;
    private CustomerOrder order;

    private List orderList = new ArrayList();
    private List customerList = new ArrayList();
    private Category category;
    private List categoryList = new ArrayList();

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        //processRequest(request, response);
        HttpSession session;

        String userPath = request.getServletPath();
        //customer list
        if (userPath.equals("/admin/showCustomers")){
            customerList = customerFacade.findAll();
            request.setAttribute("customerList", customerList);
        }

        //order list
        else if (userPath.equals("/admin/viewOrders")){
            orderList = customerOrderFacade.findAll();
            request.setAttribute("orderList", orderList);
        }
        //customer records of particular customer
        else if (userPath.equals("/admin/customerRecord")){
            //customer id from user request url
            String customerId = request.getQueryString();
            //get details of customer needs casting back
            customer = customerFacade.find(Integer.parseInt(customerId));
            request.setAttribute("customerRecord", customer);
            //get customer's order details
            order = customerOrderFacade.findByCustomer(customer);
            request.setAttribute("order", order);    
        }

        else if (userPath.equals("/admin/orderRecord")){
            //get customer id from order request
            String orderId = request.getQueryString();
            //get order details by mapping orders and customer
            Map orderMap = orderManager.getOrderDetails(Integer.parseInt(orderId));
            //place order details into app's scope by mapping
            request.setAttribute("customer", orderMap.get("customer"));
            request.setAttribute("products", orderMap.get("products"));


        }
        else if (userPath.equals("/admin/showCategory")){
            categoryList = categoryFacade.findAll();
            request.setAttribute("categoryList", categoryList);


        }
        else if (userPath.equals("/admin/logout")){
            try {
                session = request.getSession();
                session.invalidate();

                response.sendRedirect("/e-Shop/admin/");
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.toString();
            }


        }
        //forward request internally
        userPath = "/admin/index.jsp";
        try {
            request.getRequestDispatcher(userPath).forward(request, response);
        }
        catch (ServletException | IOException ex){
            ex.toString();
        }



    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        //processRequest(request, response);
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");  
        String userPath = request.getServletPath();  
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();


        Validator validator = new Validator() {};
        if (userPath.equals("/admin/addCategory")){
            if (category != null){
                String name = request.getParameter("name");
                boolean validationErrorFlag;
                validationErrorFlag = validator.validateForm(name, request);
                // if validation error found, return  to same
                if (validationErrorFlag == true) {
                    request.setAttribute("validationErrorFlag", validationErrorFlag);

                }
                else {
                    request.setAttribute("name" , name);
                    Category addCategory = categoryManager.addCategory(name);
                    userPath = "/admin/showCategory";
                }


            }

        }

        // use RequestDispatcher to forward request internally
        String url = userPath + ".jsp";
        try {
            request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
        }
        catch (ServletException | IOException ex){
            ex.toString();
        }

    }


}
```

**My addCategory.jsp**

```
    <script src="../js/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type ="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#addCatForm").validate({
                rules: {
                    name: {
                        required: true
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <!-- main container starts -->
    <div class="container maincontainer">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <h1>Add Category: </h1>
                    <form id ="addCatForm" action="<c:url value='/admin/addCategory'/>" method="post">
                        <c:if test="${!empty validationErrorFlag}">
                            <c:if test="${!empty nameError}"><p>Name</p></c:if>
                        </c:if>

                        <p><strong>Category Name:</strong>
                        <input class ="form-control" type="text" size="20" name="name"></p>
                        <p><input class ="btn-success" type="submit" value="submit"></p>

                    </form>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <h1>Side bar</h1>
                <p>Something</p>        
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- main container ends here -->
    <div class="pullfooter"></div>

<div class ="jumbotron">
<p>Jumbo</p>
</div>
<div class="pullfooter"></div>
```

And

**CategoryFacade session bean**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package session;

import entity.Category;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

/**
 *
 * @author Admin
 */
@Stateless
public class CategoryFacade extends AbstractFacade<Category> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "e-ShopPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public CategoryFacade() {
        super(Category.class);
    }

}
```

**CategoryManager Bean**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package session;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import entity.Category;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagement;
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagementType;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
/**
 *
 * @author Admin
 */
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class CategoryManager {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "e-ShopPU")
    private EntityManager em;
    @EJB
    private CategoryFacade categoryFacade;

    public Category addCategory(String name) {
        Category category = new Category();
        category.setName(name);
        em.persist(category); 
        return category;
    }

    // Add business logic below. (Right-click in editor and choose
    // "Insert Code > Add Business Method")

}
```

**ProductManager class**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package session;


import entity.Category;
import entity.Product;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.annotation.Resource;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.SessionContext;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagement;
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagementType;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;


/**

 * @author Admin
 */
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class ProductManager {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "e-ShopPU")
    private EntityManager em;
    // Add business logic below. (Right-click in editor and choose
    // "Insert Code > Add Business Method")
    @Resource
    private SessionContext context;
    @EJB
    private ProductFacade productFacade;

    public Product addProduct(String name, Double price, String description, String product_img , Category category) {
        Product product = new Product();

        product.setName(name);
        product.setPrice(BigDecimal.ZERO);
        product.setDescription(description);
        product.setCategoryId(category);

        product.setProductImg(product_img);

         em.persist(product); 
        return product;

    }



}
```

**ProductFacade**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package session;

import entity.Product;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

/**
 *
 * @author Admin
 */
@Stateless
public class ProductFacade extends AbstractFacade<Product> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "e-ShopPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public ProductFacade() {
        super(Product.class);
    }

}
```

**Product.Java Entity class**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author Admin
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findById", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByName", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.name = :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByPrice", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.price = :price"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByDescription", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.description = :description"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByLastUpdate", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.lastUpdate = :lastUpdate"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByProductImg", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.productImg = :productImg")})
public class Product implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 256)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    // @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "price")
    private BigDecimal price;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "last_update")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date lastUpdate;
    @Size(max = 1024)
    @Column(name = "product_img")
    private String productImg;
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Category categoryId;

    public Product() {
    }

    public Product(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Product(Integer id, String name, BigDecimal price, String description, Date lastUpdate) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.description = description;
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Date getLastUpdate() {
        return lastUpdate;
    }

    public void setLastUpdate(Date lastUpdate) {
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }

    public String getProductImg() {
        return productImg;
    }

    public void setProductImg(String productImg) {
        this.productImg = productImg;
    }

    public Category getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(Category categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Product)) {
            return false;
        }
        Product other = (Product) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entity.Product[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

**Category.java entity bean**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

/**
 *
 * @author Admin
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Category.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Category c"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Category.findById", query = "SELECT c FROM Category c WHERE c.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Category.findByName", query = "SELECT c FROM Category c WHERE c.name = :name")})
public class Category implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "categoryId")
    private Collection<Product> productCollection;

    public Category() {
    }

    public Category(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Category(Integer id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Product> getProductCollection() {
        return productCollection;
    }

    public void setProductCollection(Collection<Product> productCollection) {
        this.productCollection = productCollection;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Category)) {
            return false;
        }
        Category other = (Category) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entity.Category[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

Can any one point me mistake ans help me solve issues?

Comment: TL;DR. Please provide the relevant code to replicate your problem. I don't think we need to check through all EJBs and the whole code to check for a specific issue.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza you can just check where i have mistaken in these parts - AdminServlet, addCategory.jsp, categoryManager and ProductManager.